# Python Pandas frequency string comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

I've been writing a class that uses pandas dataframes sampled at specific frequenciess. The arguments it uses to specify these frequencies are the [frequency strings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) commonly used in pandas (e.g. 'H', '15min', 'D')

One of my methods needs to compare these frequencies to each other - how many of one fits into the other. Is there a smart, direct way to do this? I wrote the following but it seems so clunky and indirect:

```
def _get_relative_timediff(self, freq1, freq2):
    """ Returns how many (based on seconds) of frequency 2 goes into frequency 1
    """
    old = pd.period_range(start='1/1/1900', freq=freq1, periods=2)[1].to_timestamp()
    new = pd.period_range(start='1/1/1900', freq=freq2, periods=2)[1].to_timestamp()

    old = (old - pd.to_datetime('1/1/1900')).seconds
    new = (new - pd.to_datetime('1/1/1900')).seconds

    relative = float(old/new)

    return relative
```

It works:

```
my_object._get_relative_timediff('8H', 'min')
480.0
```

But I have to imagine there's a better way (or should be). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.to_timedelta` can be used to convert a str to a time period. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def to_timedelta(freq):
    # Add '1' to freq that doesn't have any digit
    if not bool(re.search(r'\d', freq)):
        freq = '1{}'.format(freq)

    # Convert str to datetime.timedelta
    return pd.to_timedelta(freq)

def get_relative_timediff(freq1, freq2):
    return to_timedelta(freq1) / to_timedelta(freq2)

print get_relative_timediff('8H', 'min')
print get_relative_timediff('4D', '8H')
```

And you get:

```
480.0
12.0
```

Notice I have to manually add a '1' to frequency without any digits.